# How to specify wildcard source in Android.mk in a different dir to jni

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, wildcard

I am trying to use a lot of source files in a different dir. to jni ASWELL as source in jni

How can I specify them all for LOCAL_SRC_FILES using wildcards ?

e.g

```
jni/source1.c
jni/source1.h
jni/../../../C/source2.c
:
jni/../../../C/sourcen.c
jni/../../../C/subdir1/source1.c
:
jni/../../../C/subdir1/sourcen.c
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that is fairly simple:-

In the jni/Android.mk file JUST include the other make files with relative paths

e.g.

```
include ../../../C/Android.mk
include ../../../C/subdir1/Android.mk
```

And in each of the included make files I used the wildcard routines [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/nUJR4JAKMeY)

And to build the files in jni I just included a differently named .mk file in the jni dir:

```
include jni/SourceInJni.mk
```

As the files are included they do not have to be called Android.mk, just the controlling one in jni/

When the number of source files got VERY large I had to use

```
LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true
```

in one of the included .mk files